# I have a button/link which I need to click on but can't figure it out

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have one of those links masqueraded as a button on a form which I need to click but I can't figure out how to do it, this is what the element looks like:

```html
<td id="pt1:r1:0:cf22" class="CreateQuoteBigButtonCell">
  <a id="pt1:r1:0:cl7u" class="af_commandLink" onclick="return false;" href="#">
    <table id="pt1:r1:0:tl6u" summary="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="pt1:r1:0:rl14u">
          <td id="pt1:r1:0:cf23u" class="CreateQuoteBigButtonCell1"><img id="pt1:r1:0:i9u" class="af_image" src="/portal/images/quote/addaproduct.png"></td>
          <td id="pt1:r1:0:cf24u">
            <table id="pt1:r1:0:rl15u" summary="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td id="pt1:r1:0:cf25u" class="CreateQuoteBigButtonCell2">Add a Product or Service</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <table id="pt1:r1:0:rl16u" summary="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td id="pt1:r1:0:cf26u" class="CreateQuoteBigButtonCell3">Product or service</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </a>
</td>
```

I've tried using find_element_by_xpath using the table ID but it doesn't seem to work, is there any other option I can look at?

My code currently looks like this:

`browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Quote Details']"))
clickExpPack = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pt1:r1:0:cf16c1"]/tbody/tr/td')))
clickExpPack.click()`

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_class_name('CreateQuoteBigButtonCell3').click()`

Comment: Thanks @Stack - but it errored out with : Message: Unable to locate element: .CreateQuoteBigButtonCell3‌​

Comment: @SeanLow Still now I am unable to see the <iframe> tag as you did `browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Quote Details']"))`. More over I also don't find any element whose `id` or `xpath` contains  `pt1:r1:0:cf16c1` which you copied as the relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: The frame was found when I right clicked on the page where the element is and saw there was a Frame Source option and got the info from there.

The pt1:r1:0:cf16c1 - I'm not sure what happened, looks like it changed over the weekend, the one I pasted in the DOM should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class=​'CreateQuoteBigButtonCell3‌']").click()
```

> or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id=​'pt1:r1:0:cf16cl‌']").click()
```

> or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class=​'CreateQuoteBigButtonCell3‌' and @id=​'pt1:r1:0:cf16cl‌']").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB - none of those worked, they all errored out with the following message: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: @SeanLow Can you update the Question with your exact code block along with the relevant HTML DOM along with the error stack trace please? Thanks

Comment: here is where I display my true level of incompetency - how do I extract the HTML DOM?

Comment: Here is what you need to do:1.Open your Firefox.2.Search for  "firebug addon".3.From the suggestions open url Firebug :: Add-ons for Firefox - Firefox Add-ons - Mozilla(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) 4. Click `Add to Firefox` button.5.Click `Install`.6.Restart Firefox.7.Browse to website.8.You will find `Firebug icon` at the top right corner of the Webpage.9.Click on `Firebug icon`, it turns Orange.10.On the Firebug console click on the `Inspect Element` pointer & click on an element on the page.11.Element gets highlighted in DOM.12.Copy the nearby areas.13.Paste it.

Comment: <tr id="pt1:r1:0:rl14u"><td id="pt1:r1:0:cf23u" class="CreateQuoteBigButtonCell1">
<img id="pt1:r1:0:i9u" class="af_image" src="/portal/images/quote/addaproduct.png">
</td><td id="pt1:r1:0:cf24u"><table id="pt1:r1:0:rl15u" summary="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody><tr><td id="pt1:r1:0:cf25u" class="CreateQuoteBigButtonCell2">Add a Product</td>
</tr></tbody></table><table id="pt1:r1:0:rl16u" summary="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody><tr><td id="pt1:r1:0:cf26u" class="CreateQuoteBigButtonCell3">
Product or Service</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>

Comment: see comment above - basically, it looks like a button or link in the browser, but when I inspect the element, there is no click action or anything that resembles a button nor is there a a href tag that I can use to click the link

Comment: @SeanLow The last part: 1.Click on the `edit` button under your question. 2.Place the cursor where you want to put the copied HTML DOM.3. Click on  `JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet`. 4. Within the Code Snippet window, select the `HTML` part. 5. Paste the copied HTML DOM contents there. 6. Next click on `Tidy` link so the HTML DOM representation is easy for SO volunteers to analyze. 7. Finally, click on `Save and Insert into post`. :) Thanks

Comment: Done! Thanks for all your help so far!